# How do I draw a specific border in CSS?

Tags: html, css, web

I want to make a border like this:

Before:
[image: Page without border]

I want after  to look like this:
[image: Page with border]

"Lable" is an `li` tag like:

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>           
</ul>
```

The box below is a `div` element like this:

```
<div class="main-container">

</div>
```

I tried like this:

```css
li{
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    border-left: 1px solid red;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
}

div{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

However, the two borders overlap and are disgusting.

**I would like to avoid the `table-cell` method, because it was impossible
to design a reactive type by wrongly calculating the area.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `border-bottom:1px white solid;` to your active tab and increase its `padding-bottom`. Now Adjust them with `z-index`. That's it :)

see link below.

https://jsfiddle.net/vaishuk/kpova28h/

Comment: Thank you this is really easy! Happy new year Thank you and Regards

Comment: Most Welcome. Happy new year to you too :)

Answer (score 2):

This may helpful

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}
/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {     
    
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {    
    border-left:1px solid red;    
    border-top:1px solid red;
    border-right:1px solid red;    
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
}
/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid red; 
    margin-top:-1px;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent" style="display:block">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="main-container">
<ul>
    <li class="list-item active">one</li>
    <li class="list-item ">two</li>
    <li class="list-item ">three</li>           
</ul>
</div>



 <script>
       $('ul li.list-item').click(function(){
       $('ul li.list-item').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    </script>
```